# How can I get a Map key that is an object?

Tags: javascript

I have a Map collection with 3 elements:

```
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set(124, 'hello worlds!');
myMap.set(true, 98);

let obj = {'site': 'stackoverflow'};
myMap.set(obj, true);

console.log(myMap);
```

How I can select the object key with `get()`?

Comment: `myMap.get(obj)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const myMap = new Map();

myMap.set(124, 'hello worlds!');
myMap.set(true, 98);

let obj = {'site': 'stackoverflow'};
myMap.set(obj, true);

console.log(myMap.get(obj));
```